"Bootstrap broker localhost:9092 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected "
This connection failure error continuously logging in project, how can I stop this even when kafka server is down . I tried to remove property from application.properties
spring.kafka.producer.bootstrap-servers=localhost:9092 trying to connect using Producerconfig file in java
I am trying to avoid this log printing in spring boot project while project is running but kafkaserver is down.
